# Show all numbers from the fibonacci calculation

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is part of my online class module and I need to write a program where the user inputs a `number(n)` and the program then prints the first `n` numbers in the fibonacci series.

I currently wrote the program so that it prints out the `fibonacci` number at a certain position.

for example, if I enter "7", it will print "13".

```
n = int(input("Enter a number:"))
fibonacciSeries = ((1+sqrt(5))**n-(1-sqrt(5))**n) /(2**n*sqrt(5))
print (fibonacciSeries)
```

How can I modify this code so that it prints out all the numbers leading up to the 7th number in the series?

Comment: Do you know the recursive form as well as the closed for for Fibonacci? Or stick the closed form in a loop?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to repeat an operation you'll need loops, if you also need to store the result of the repeated operation you need a list. So, use a list comprehension to create a list of all numbers until `i` (renamed in order to use in `range`).

Then, you can unpack in the `print` call to view all the numbers produced. Also, `/` is floating point division; you're probably after floor division `//` here so I modified that for you:

```
i = int(input("Enter a number:"))
fibonacciSeries = [((1+sqrt(5))**n-(1-sqrt(5))**n)//(2**n*sqrt(5)) for n in range(1, i+1)]
print ("Fibonacci Nums: ", *fibonacciSeries)
```

The expression:

```
[(...) for n in range(1, 1+1)]
```

will repeat the operations in `(...)` for `i` times.

This results in:

```
Enter a number:7
Fibonacci Nums:  1.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 5.0 8.0 13.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put it on a cycle, like this:

```
n = int(input("Enter a number:"))
for i in range(n + 1):
  fib = ((1+sqrt(5))**n-(1-sqrt(5))**n) /(2**n*sqrt(5))
  print(fib)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... assuming your calculation is correct (It may be, I've just never seen that before)

```
n = int(input("Enter a number:"))
for i in range(1,n+1):
   fibonacciSeries = ((1+sqrt(5))**i-(1-sqrt(5))**i) /(2**i*sqrt(5))
   print (fibonacciSeries)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've already calculated the first `n-1` values of the Fibonacci sequence, then there's no reason not to use them to determine the `n`th term.

```
a, b = 0, 1 #set a=0, b=1
for _ in range(n): #do the following n times
    print(a) #print one term each loop, for a total of n terms
    a, b = b, a+b #advance the sequence one step
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def fibonacci(z):
   a,b = 0,1
   while True:
   for y in xrange(z):
       yield a
       a,b = b, a+b



for i in fibonacci(5):
    print i
```

The fibonacci generator will pop out the numbers you want.  I don't know if you have eventually you will have anything else to do besides print them, but anytime you are outputting a series, generators are highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
def fibonacci():
    x,y = 1,1
    n=int(input("Enter number: "))
    n_int=int(n-2)
    for i in range (n_int):
        x,y=y,x+y
        print(x)
    print(y)
```